# Deciphering the identifier for a diode

Tags: diodes, identification

I need to replace a burned-out diode.

It is marked P6KE16A 240K.

[image]

What do these numbers mean?  Is there any information encoded?  (e.g. 16A, 240K-Ohm)

Is this information sufficient for sourcing a new part? I can't find an identical part.

I can find a part ([here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5-X-DIODE-TVS-16V-600W-Part-P6KE16A-/350819447971?)) that matches P6KE16A -- how can I know whether it is a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 1):

This is a suppressor diode (TVS suppressor).

600W, 16V, unidirectional (yours is "A"), for bidirectional it would be "CA".

EDIT:

Lets just say it is a powerful zener diode.

Yours should read 0.7V in the forward direction, and should start clamping at around 13.xxV in the other direction. You can test the 0.7V with a mutimeter diode tester, the 13.xx V you can test with a power supply of about 18V minimum and a series resistor, say 100 Ohm if you use a 18V power supply.